# how to get get Byte Frequency Data to work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, mobile

I've got a very annoying iOS bug (not suprising). I'm trying to make a very basic audio analyser script to pick up the frequency/level of the audio as its playing.

It works on desktop, chrome, safari. On mobile iOS the audio works , but the frequency data returns 0...

Codepen: http://codepen.io/LuckyDe/pen/kXZqNm?editors=1011

```
function playAudio() {
console.log('play audio')
audio = document.getElementById("audioPiece");

context = new AudioContext()
analyser = context.createAnalyser();

source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(analyser);
source.connect(context.destination);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
audio.play();
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

function draw() {
  if (context.currentTime < audio.duration) {
    drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
  var getData = (frequencyData[8] * 100) / 256 - 30;
   console.log(frequencyData[8]);
  playButton.innerHTML = "draw" + getData;
}
draw();
```

}

i cant get audio to work cross origin on codepen so direct link http://www.luckyde.com/js/AudioFrequency/test1/index.html

Is there any workaround/way to solve this so that it works on a tablet/iphone? Thanks so much